# Isn't Skaro stuck in the Time War?

Tags: doctor-who

I watched the prequel to Asylum of the Daleks, and in it the Doctor is told to go to Skaro.

Isn't Skaro stuck in the time bubble that the Doctor created to isolate the Time War from the rest of universe?

How can he go there?

Comment: Good question +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer, surprisingly, [is no it was not](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Great_Time_War#Conclusion).

The only reason Gallifrey was timelocked was to prevent Rassilon from initiating the Ultimate Sanction which would wipe out all life in the universe and cause an ascension of the Time Lords to be beings of pure cognizance rather than organic life as well as destroy Time itself.

The Eighth (or possibly Ninth) Doctor's use of The Moment timelocked all of the other Time Lords (bar the Doctor, and the Master who ran away from the war out of fear and the drumbeat in his head), the Daleks, the horrors unleashed by both sides such as Nightmare Child, as well as Gallifrey where the Ultimate Sanction was located.

Skaro had already become a wasteland at this point and was the Dalek capital in name only. Thus the Doctor had no reason to time lock it. They primarily used their spaceships to move around and congregate, which is shown in The Stolen Earth and Journey's End and again in Asylum of the Daleks. Though the Parliment ship is either a new canon, or a retcon as Daleks are supposed to only answer to the Supreme Dalek/Emperor Dalek rather than debate in Parliament.

Comment: Not necessarily much debate.... "Exterminate!"  "Anyone second he motion?" "Exterminate!" "Alright, all those in favour?" "EXTERMINATE!"  "The exterminates have it, motion passed.'

Comment: @dlanod, The fact they would need a second motion to affirm Dalek superiority is a very un-Dalek-like quality. :P Why waste time passing motions when you could be EXTERMINATINGGGGG!

Answer (score -1):

My theory is that the time war is time locked but any events that happened before the time war on skaro and gallifrey aren't time locked. So this episode on a whoniverse timeline would've took place before the time war.

Comment: I thought the Doctor explicitly mentions that it's Skaro post Time War, which is why it's so ravaged.

Comment: The implication a time lock if that you cannot reach the space via any means. No more changing its past, present, or wibbly-wobbly future. It is more than fixed, it is simply unreachable.