# Continuity and Skaro

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

Has it ever been explained (barring John Peel's book, *The War of the Daleks* which hasn't been widely accepted) how Skaro can exist when the 7th Doctor caused its destruction?

Comment: If an explanation exists, it is going to be pure timey-wimey ball.

Comment: Continuity is a lie! Wibbly wobbly, Timey-wimey!

Comment: The Daleks brought it back - that's the explanation given by Davros in "The Magician's Apprentice". I don't think there's any more detail (and I leave it to someone else to find the exact quote for an answer).

Comment: **MISSY**: 
*They brought it back. They built it
again! No!!*
**CLARA**: *What is it? Where are we?*
**MISSY**: *This is* -
THE DOCTOR, staring in horror, completes the sentence.
**THE DOCTOR**: - *Skaro!! (Rounds on Davros) You’re brought me to Skaro!*

Comment: Is Skaro time-locked like Gallifrey is (was)? What if they just went back to Skaro at a time when it still existed? Maybe that should be another question by itself...

Comment: Skaro wasn't stated as being time locked, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/isnt-skaro-stuck-in-the-time-war. If it was destroyed how could they bring it back., so "They built it again" must refer to the city?

Comment: Or they just traveled in time, and brought it back from a time when it still existed. They have the technology, after all...

Comment: Would have thought that if Fixed Points occur, then that would be a pretty big Fixed Point.

Answer (score 3):

Given that Skaro's sun must be considerably smaller than a supergiant (otherwise Skaro itself could not exist) the explosion caused by the Hand Of Omega could well have been considerably weaker than a natural supernova. 
It's possible the planet itself survived, even if all Daleks on it were destroyed.
It is worth noting that Skaro itself is seen in 'Asylum Of The Daleks', looking in a much worse state than in 'The Magician's Apprentice'. Possibly the Daleks restored their world to it's former glory in between those stories.

Answer (score 1):

Having read up on this, first the Omega Device was meant to make a star go supernovae and become a black hole, and I think even a "small supernovae" would be quite destructive.

According to this [reference](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Remembrance_of_the_Daleks): "At the time of broadcast, it **unambiguously** showed the onscreen destruction of the Dalek homeworld, Skaro", with the added comment *that this was forgotten*(!) when the series came back (in fact, even in the Dr Who movie since this involved the Master apparently being exterminated by the Daleks on Skaro).

However, tardis wikia also states [here](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Skaro): "Skaro was apparently destroyed when, as planned by the Seventh Doctor, the Hand of Omega caused its sun to go supernova. The stellar explosion released a shockwave which quickly struck the nearby world. It ripped and burned the planet to smithereens. (TV: Remembrance of the Daleks) *However, at least part of the planet persisted, though in ruins and with the conditions of its environment even worse than after the Thousand Year War*. (TV: Asylum of the Daleks)".

I remember at the time there being some discussion about the Doctor destroying Skaro, since not only would he destroy the Daleks but also all other sentient life that also existed at the time.

Comment: PS: According to http://www.polishheritage.ca/news_detail.aspx?cat_id=16&page_id=0&news_id=484 "Skaro was a small Polish agricultural settlement, situated some 80km northeast of Edmonton. It was settled at the turn of the 20th Century, and its residents built a small chapel of Our Lady of Good Counsel in 1904" and at the moment the weather is not too bad: https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/alberta/skaro?wx_auto_reload=